# Getting over the "unlock hump" on the Moon

Tags: adventure-capitalist

My progression on Earth and Mars is going quite smoothly...I am able to double up on Angels in quite a reasonable amount of time.  Unfortunately I can't say the same about the Moon.  I'm having a real hard time getting over the "unlock hump", as I call it.  Most of my investments have an insane multiplier for their next unlock, but along with that require a crazy number of investments.  Screenshots below for reference.

The problem is that I still have a lot of investments to go to unlock anything new, but my income rate is making development glacial.  I'm having to pay in the sexvigintillions and up for new investments, but my best investments are only earning quinvigintillions.  I already have quite a few angels (in the undecillions, see final screenshot), but it's also taking forever to "double up" on them.  Upgrades are also a long ways away, and wouldn't help much anyways.  So I'm not sure how to proceed.

Is the Moon supposed to be this hard, or am I missing something?  It seems odd, considering that Mars is going quite well for me.  I've considered purchasing another golden ticket, but I'm not sure what I would put it on, or if it would even really help...

---

### Investments

[image: Moon investments]

### Upcoming unlocks

[image: Upcoming unlocks]

### Angels

[image: Angels]

Comment: It certainly used to be a lot harder when it first came out, it was sooo slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to use the Moon Guide that someone posted on Steam.  There are many graphs on Earth, Moon, and Mars showing the profit gains.  Here's the guide for the Moon: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=443045440

It's very lengthy, but here's the first part that gives a brief strategy without going into specifics.

> This strategy works by making you hit milestones which multiply the profit gained from businesses. What follows is a brief list of things you should aim for, followed by a lengthier explanation which tries to be a bit more elaborate, especially if you are stuck at certain parts.
>   The list only contains business-specific milestones. You should purchase upgrades on your own.
>   For the "x of everything" milestones, check out the table below.
>
> Reach the following investment quantities in that order:
>
> 1. 160 Moon Shoes (cost ~ $233,846)
> 2. 120 Payday Clones (cost ~ $140.458 million)
> 3. 90 Oxygen Bars (cost ~ $12.788 billion)
> 4. 64 Cheese Mines (cost ~ $7.554 trillion)
> 5. 180 Oxygen Bars (cost ~ $29.874 trillion)
> 6. 128 Cheese Mines (cost ~ $18.854 quadrillion)
> 7. 150 Werewolf Colonies (cost ~ $9.926 quintillion)
> 8. 360 Oxygen Bars (cost ~ $162.992 quintillion)
> 9. 450 Werewolf Colonies (cost ~ $392.363 nonillion)
> 10. 2880 Oxygen Bars (cost ~ $3.365 septentrigintillion)
> 11. 2160 Amusement Parks (cost ~ $93.007 unquinquagintillion)
> 12. 2600 Helium-3 Farms (cost ~ $8.154 quattuorquinquagintillion)
> 13. 2300 Amusement Parks (cost ~ $326.993 quattuorquinquagintillion)
> 14. 3500 Werewolf Colonies (cost ~ $674.175 quinquinquagintillion)
> 15. 2540 Amusement Parks (cost ~ $7.571 sexagintillion)
> 16. 3800 Werewolf Colonies (cost ~ $26.648 sexagintillion)
> 17. 3000 Helium-3 Farms (cost ~ $15.506 duosexagintillion)
> 18. 4100 Werewolf Colonies (cost ~ $1.053 quinsexagintillion)
> 19. 3000 Amusement Parks (cost ~ $175.647 septuagintillion)

So that's very basic milestones you should aim for, but the guide is very in-depth if you want to learn strategies for overcoming that hump we all hit on the moon.

Comment: Oh thanks, i saw asked Dec 14 at 2:19 and was thinking 2014 for some reason.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's helpful.  Looks like I'm between steps 9 and 10.  The jump there is crazy...cost goes from nonillions to _septentrigintillions_...that's a huge jump!

Comment: From the guide:  `Oxygen Bars outclass the other investments by several orders of magnitude at this point. In fact, you might spend weeks or months spending your money on nothing but Oxygen Bars.`.  So it sounds like I just have to grind it out.

Comment: Unfortunately.  There's several humps you have to grind out.  I'm at the point where i'm getting tretrigintillion, but i need to get septentrigintillion to hit 2880 oxygen bars.  I'm on the same rough spot.

Comment: I've been working on moon for months, maybe even a year at this point? I'm stuck between 9 and 10 as well, because that jump is impossible. 

I think it is more worthwhile to buy 600 lasers in between there so you can increase the Oxygen bars by two. After that, I'm not sure...

Comment: @Katamaritaco It's gotten much easier if you can save up enough Mega Dollars to buy Mega Tickets to boost each investment on the moon (at least the ones you are having trouble with).  If you do the events, you can also save up enough Gold to buy multipliers for each planet, but if you can get by with just the Mega Tickets, you can save the multipliers for earth (the real trouble).

Comment: @dakre18 thanks for the advice. The problem is, I've actually done that, and still have been stuck for that long. The hump appears to be practically impossible unless you're willing to pay for a massive increase...

Comment: Sadly, it's annoying, but there's 1 last option that not everyone wants to do (because you shouldn't have to).  It's easier on the PC, but mess with your date/time to give yourself free time.  Otherwise, the only option is to reclaim angels as often as you can (soon as you double angels) and/or get more multipliers (and i know that sucks).  Just make sure to get as many Mega Bucks you can from each event, and use their new feature the "Platinum Boost" that you upgrade with Mega Bucks.  Basically they've added Platinum Boost to make things faster for earth and moon.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

Achieve Tier 2 Platinum Boost on Moon

---

### Guide

1. Farm Mega Bucks (You will need 100 or 110 depending on strategy)

   - Adventures Page > Exchange Tab for *Each Planet*
   - Unlock rewards for 'X of Everything' (Check Gallery)
2. Buy Mega Tickets (You will need 10 total)

   - Each Mega Ticket can boost any single business on any planet
   - Boosting all 10 businesses on a *single* planet adds the Tier 1 Platinum Boost
3. You can either save Mega Bucks or Decrease time spent on Moon Hump:

   - Use the 10 Mega Ticket discount
   - Boost businesses one at a time (Starting with Oxygen Bar)
4. Use 10 more Mega Bucks to upgrade the Platinum Boost on Moon

---

It really was as simple has getting tier 2 platinum on moon. Hump demolished.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend that you accelerate your investor collection ahead of the typically recommended 2x existing. The investor ticker just crawls at this point too, but I've found I can get back to where I was and then some by claiming regularly when the number of new investors is 50-100% of my current pool.

I'm still in the slog right now, but it FEELS like I'm making some progress... Sometimes that's important, too. :D

Answer (score 0):

At the 7777.77 platinum multiplier you can beat the moon in around 7-8 hours!!! 777.77 at 2-3 days 77.77 at 1-2 weeks and 7.77 at 4-5 weeks no boost at 3-5 months

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Here are few suggestions:

- Buy investments in multipliers of 100, so it's more clear which investment are affordable in order to unlock the next level of investment. Buying them individually isn't worth it at this stage of the game since single upgrades doesn't make big difference and you can invest this money somewhere else where you could have the opportunity to multiple the earnings by unlocking the next stage.
- Reset the game once you've got 500x-1000x more of new angels (if the progress is slower, you can consider at least 2x).

If your game seems stuck and you collected more angels than you have already, try reseting the game, as you could get to the same place where you are fairly quickly.

Since you've spare Mega Dollars, consider buying Mega Tickets and upgrade some of the most profitable investments (such as laser investment).